# Cordova error in Xcode - No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I've been trying to create a Cordova / Phonegap application in Xcode on a new computer. But it doesn't seem to work. When I run the application on either a simulator or my iPhone I get an error message saying that 'libCordova.a' is not found.

**1 error message and 5 issues:**

```
/Users/Tim/Documents/Dropbox/Applicaties/Business/FirstProject/Xcode/FirstProject.xcodeproj
/Users/Tim/Documents/Dropbox/Applicaties/Business/FirstProject/Xcode/FirstProject.xcodeproj Missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image
/Users/Tim/Documents/Dropbox/Applicaties/Business/FirstProject/Xcode/FirstProject/Classes/AppDelegate.m
/Users/Tim/Documents/Dropbox/Applicaties/Business/FirstProject/Xcode/FirstProject/Classes/AppDelegate.m:73:25: 'invokeString' is deprecated
/Users/Tim/Documents/Dropbox/Applicaties/Business/FirstProject/Xcode/FirstProject/Classes/MainViewController.m
/Users/Tim/Documents/Dropbox/Applicaties/Business/FirstProject/Xcode/FirstProject/Classes/MainViewController.m:117:15: 'invokeString' is deprecated
/Users/Tim/Documents/Dropbox/Applicaties/Business/FirstProject/Xcode/FirstProject/Classes/MainViewController.m:121:93: 'invokeString' is deprecated
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Tim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstProject-ctanrqwggcfoubbeqbjrfvcqozpg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a'
```

- Cordova version 2.1.0
- Xcode version 4.5.1

I have not been able to install the latest cordova on my computer, on version 2.0.0 there was an installation program but in the latest version this is gone? And I already set the 'Build Active Architecture Only' to Yes and the 'Build Location' to Unique.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had exactly the same error.
The problem was that I hadn't set the 'Build Active Architecture Only' for both projects.
Your main project & the CordovaLib.xcodeproj.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem:

- Open your project in Xcode.
- Click on your project.
- Click on your project under Targets.
- Hit the build phases tab.
- Open “Copy Bundle Resources” near the bottom.
- Look for any resources listed in red, and drag/drop them manually there.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

in the CordovaLib Build Settings. Under Architectures -> Valid Architectures, I removed armv6. this worked for me! (iphone 4s phonegap 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

The installer is gone because it is no longer required. Have you followed *all* the steps from the very helpful getting started guide here? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS